# Function overloads, documentation almost identical

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I have two `acquire` functions and, besides their arguments, the documentation is identical. How should I handle this? Should I add something like "The same general notes found in function X's documentation also apply here"? If not, does Doxygen offer some kind of tool for dealing with cases like this?

```
ResourcePtr<T> acquire(const std::string& file);
ResourcePtr<T> acquire(const void* buffer, std::size_t size);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Doxygen, so this answer is purely on my documentation approach.

When I document in a situation like where two topics are nearly identical, I either repeat the shared information in both (preferred) or I write something similar to the following:

"Function Y is similar to function X. Function Y takes the arguments abc and [put how it works differently here]...

For more information on these functions, see ."

In this case I'd document the simpler one and add the additional info to the more complex one.

A third way is to break out the common doc from both, if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

From [This Page](http://www.cisst.org/resources/software/cis/doxygen-documentation.html):

*Use the \sa (See Also) keyword to link to related variables, methods, or classes. This is the equivalent command to \see tag.*

Comment: I'm not sure that's the intended use of \sa. I used it before, but only for classes that are somehow related, not for referencing other documentation.